# How can I prevent a line break between option and parameter using `.RB` and `.IR`?

Tags: man, groff

When writing a manual page of a command, the SYNOPSIS contains:

```roff
.RB [ \-v
.IR version ]
```

Unfortunately when formatting the SYNOPSIS there is a line break between "[-v" and "version]".

How can I avoid that?

### Adding the Obvious

As requested multiple times, here is a longer sample input for the lack of imagination, as well as a screenshot showing the problem:
[image: Screenshot of formatted sample (problem area highlighted)]

And here is the source:

```man
.TH FOOBAR-DEMO 8 2022-03-16 "Charlie Brown" "System Administration"
.\"
.SH NAME
foobar-demo \- demonstration of manual formatting
.\"
.SH SYNOPSIS
.na
.nr hy-mode-save \n[.hy]
.hy 0
.B foobar-demo123
.RB [ \-a
.IR match_spec ]
.RB [ \-\-resource-agent
.IR match_spec ]
.RB [ \-v
.IR version ]
.RB [ \-\-version
.IR version ]
.hy \n[hy-mode-save]
.ad b
.\"
.SH DESCRIPTION
The purpose of this page is none...
```

Comment: Just add some text before to shift "-v" to the end of the line.

Comment: You have an unexpected line break, or have you reached the end of the line and you want to push `[-v` to the next so it's kept adjacent to `--version]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thomas Dickey has one correct (and portable) solution but like you, I find it a bit unprepossessing due to the font selection escape sequences.  I much prefer *man*(7)'s font styling macros.

Further, the `\`  (backslash-space) escape sequence can *also* be ugly because its unbreakable space is fixed-width; on a line that undergoes adjustment, this can be noticeable and jarring.

I therefore recommend using the output line continuation escape sequence `\c` to permit an input line to end without causing the insertion of a breakable space, and the `\~` escape sequence for an unbreakable, but adjustable space.

You've turned off adjustment in your example, but that is not necessary as I will show.  By using `\~`, adjustment can be done evenly across the lines of the synopsis without causing problems.  This escape sequence is portable to all currently-maintained *troff* projects except that in Illumos.  *groff* has had it since 1991 (at least), Heirloom Doctools since September 2005, *mandoc* (which isn't a *troff* but does parse man pages) since September 2009, *neatroff* since September 2016, and Plan 9 from User Space *troff* as of August 2022.

In your example, you used the *groff* register `.hy` and *groff*'s extended interpolation syntax to get at it.  If you're using *groff*, you might want to consider its `SY`/`YS` extensions to the *man*(7) macro package for setting your command synopses.[2](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/groff_man.7.html)  (These macros also save and restore the hyphenation mode for you.)

```
.TH FOOBAR-DEMO 8 2022-03-16 "Charlie Brown" "System Administration"
.\"
.SH NAME
foobar-demo \- demonstration of manual formatting
.\"
.SH SYNOPSIS
.B foobar\-demo123 \" I escaped this hyphen as well.
.RB [ \-a\~\c
.IR match_spec ]
.RB [ \-\-resource-agent\~\c
.IR match_spec ]
.RB [ \-v\~\c
.IR version ]
.RB [ \-\-version\~\c
.IR version ]
.\"
.SH DESCRIPTION
```

Comment: Interestingly `\c` is documented as "*interrupt text processing*", and it can be queried via `\n[.int]`in `groff`. So that is rather non-obvious to me. Also I had been wondering whether I could write a "horizontal equivalent" of `.ne`, possibly using `\n[hp]` in `groff` before.

Comment: I entirely agree about the non-obviousness of \c's meaning.  I think this has led variously to avoidance when it would be useful, and cargo-cult inclusion of it when it is not.

In the forthcoming _groff_ release, its [Texinfo manual](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/groff.git/tree/doc/groff.texi#n9416), [groff(7) man page](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/groff.git/tree/man/groff.7.man#n552), and [groff_man_style(7) page](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/groff.git/tree/tmac/groff_man.7.man.in#n2609)--the last aimed at authors of man pages--try to explain \c more clearly than in the past.

Comment: I need to correct myself about the longevity of `\~` in _groff_.  It dates back not merely to December 2000 (when its support code was refactored by Werner Lemberg), but to the oldest copies of James Clark's original work that are publicly available--that means _groff_ 1.02, released 1991-06-02.

Answer (score 1):

The macros get in the way.  You can fix the problem using an escaped space (which will not split the line), like this:

```
.TH FOOBAR-DEMO 8 2022-03-16 "Charlie Brown" "System Administration"
.\"
.SH NAME
foobar-demo \- demonstration of manual formatting
.\"
.SH SYNOPSIS
.na
.nr hy-mode-save \n[.hy]
.hy 0
.B foobar-demo123
\fB[\-a\ \fImatch_spec\fR]
\fB[\-\-resource-agent\ \fImatch_spec\fR]
\fB[\-v\ \fIversion\fR]
\fB[\-\-version\ \fIversion\fR]
.hy \n[hy-mode-save]
.ad b
.\"
.SH DESCRIPTION
The purpose of this page is none...
```

Comment: Of course I could do that, but I consider explicit font commands (`\f`) to be ugly, and they make the source hard to read.

Answer (score -1):

Most likely, you have a CRLF in the line, instead of LF.

Comment: Please do not guess what I might have. In fact the lines are OK.

Comment: @U.Windl we have to guess because the information is not in your question

Comment: @White Owl Maybe explain what a difference CRLF would make over just LF.

Comment: CRLF - windows style line separator. 0D,0A in hex. \r\n in C style strings.
LF - linux style line separator. 0A in hex. \n in C style strings.

groff adds a line feed if it sees the \r in the text.